Is the Holy Spirit necessary for hermeneutics?
Basis for this question is this answer:
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/95280/32251
In particular:

This answer is likely to be closed as off-topic. The reason is multi-faceted but the main reason is the LLM's like ChatGPT does not actually convey any meaning and is not motivated by the Holy Spirit. -@Dottard

My takeaway is that the Holy Spirit is a necessary part of hermeneutics.
I therefore have this question:
Is the Holy Spirit really necessary for proper biblical Hermeneutics?
(I don't mean theology, or relationship with God but specifically Hermeneutics)

For clarity's sake, you need to specify whether you are referring to a Divine Person or a mere influence.

@NigelJ Not sure where you are getting at. Does that change the answer? If so I am interested in both.

The inference is supported by the argument in 1 Corinthians ch2, to the effect that God's word cannot be understood by human wisdom alone.
v11 "For what person knows a man's thoughts except the spirit of the man that is in him? So also no one comprehends the thoughts of God except the Spirit of God" (RSV).
So Paul's teaching must be given "in words not taught by humam wisdom but taught by the Spirit" (v13), and they must be taught "to spiritual people" (PNEUMATIKOIS). A man who lacks the Spirit cannot understand the gifts of God, because they are "spiritually discerned" (v14).
Indeed Paul asserts elsewhere that the Jews had an incomplete understanding of the meaning of their own scriptures because, in the absence of the interpretive guidance of the Holy Spirit "a veil lies over their minds" (2 Corinthians ch3 v15). Since this was preventing them from seeing the new covenant in the scriptures, I would suggest that part of the veil was a failure to look beyond the most literal interpretation (the use of phylacteries being one of the symptoms).
Admittedly PNEUMATIKOIS is an ambiguous word which could also mean "by spiritual things", a translation which the RSV offers in a footnote. But I prefer their main text translation "to those who possess the Spirit" because it seems to fit better into the immediate context.
The choice being offered by Paul in these chapters is between God's wisdom imparted by the Holy Spirit and human wisdom without the Spirit. Only the Spirit can give us full understanding of the text. I would have thought that AI sits firmly on the human side of that boundary line.

The source material that chatbots use is crucial. Some of these sources might indeed be inspired. It's also possible to limit the information used to a single source, perhaps a set of commentaries or even the Holy Bible itself. The primary benefit would be to extract, organize, and summarize existing information. So where does the Holy Spirit act in all this? I would think that a person, despite reading the Bible, commentaries, or chatbot summaries, would still not understand what they're reading or have a sense that the scriptures are being applied to their lives. The text would seem dead.

"Since this was preventing them from seeing the new covenant in the scriptures" - this is also what mormons say prevents non-LDS from seeing the truth of the Book of Mormon. Hence the emphasis on the "burning in the bosom" in Mormonism

It really depends on the nature of the text and its authorship - if you assume the underlying authorship and intent is in any way divine then awareness of that divine author will be necessary to exegete it fully. Direct intervention by that same divine author would be your best possible chance to interpret it as intended.
However, hermeneutics is also a somewhat mechanical process - interpreting texts based on various types of context, authorship and awareness of the target audience. LLMs prove themselves to be very adept at this type of task, interpreting a range of user queries based on their context, authorship and target audience. The more details you supply around this, the easier it is for the model to interpret, depending on how it is trained.
Indeed, often the materials which LLMs are referencing or copying are from human authors who have engaged in hermeneutics themselves, for better or worse - and so having access to these can put models at an advantage.
If a model were starting from scratch with purely the mechanical details of the passage and question, then it would be predictably fairly poor. But we've had many passable or even good quality LLM answers appear on the site over the past 3 years, and so even if one accepts that the Holy Spirit or other divine influence is necessary to engage in hermeneutics, this doesn't necessarily mean that authors without this type of influence (including LLMs) won't arrive at good answers some/most of the time.

Some Christians may say that only the Spirit can lead people to have correct understandings of scripture. Other Christians say that the normal process of reading comprehension can lead to correct understandings.
In either case, AI does not have any capacity to understand scripture, as it does not have any understanding of anything.

But this still means that the necessity for the Holy Spirit in Hermeneutics is somewhat debatable. I also think that we are putting an unreasonable high standard on LLMs. LLMs are a tool in the toolset of Hermeneutics. Just like Bible commentary or Greek dictionaries. Or would you say that those things need to be able to "understand" in order to be a useful tool?

There's very little in common between LLMs and commentaries or dictionaries.

Just like drills and ladders, but nevertheless, both are needed to build a house. My point is that both are tools and that tools are not required to have the ability of understanding to be useful. But I created this question to properly investigate this topic: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/does-a-llm-need-to-understand-in-order-to-be-a-useful-tool-in-hermeneutics

This is going to be long.  I apologize.  It's a big question.
This question reminds me of the great prophet of Tongue-In-Cheek Samuel Clemens (aka Mark Twain):  “It ain't the parts of the Bible that I can't understand that bother me, it's the parts that I do understand.”
Does one need the Holy Spirit to interpret 2 + 2 and understand it to mean 4?  I’m starting an answer to this highly complex question with a very, very basic part of the question.  Hopefully, it starts to pull apart the question into part we can grapple with.  The obvious answer is, "No".  There appears to be no relevancy.
But, in one sense, yes.  We wouldn’t even have a ‘2’ if it weren’t for God’s involvement in the first place.  Someone might notice I substituted ‘God’ in for ‘Holy Spirit’ there; but, where does one draw the line between the two persons?  Immediately, we’re into defining fine nuances of meaning (which is kind of a necessary complexity with your question).  But, this fine distinction really doesn’t answer the question other than to point out that there needs to be some effort given to demarcating the lines so as to understand what is really being asked.  And, that’s not easy to do.   I’ve been thinking about this question for probably 40 years.
God Meets Us Here
We’re talking about a God who is spirit actually communicating with people who are human.  How does that work?  What language would he use?  And, if we take what is given to us, as it has been given to us, what is the nature of that specific instantiation of language?  If he communicates in His language (whatever that could possibly mean), how could we understand.  He is, however, perfectly capable at communicating in our language. And, I think, that fact turns out to be very important. Hermeneutics becomes important because God communicating in our language.
If He simply injects the meaning into our minds, then what is the relevance of hermeneutics to begin with?  And, if we can communicate that meaning, then why didn’t he just do that, with words?  After all, He has revealed truth to us.
So, that is to say:  His normal communication with us is basically incarnational in nature.  He makes the long trip to us.  We don’t make the long trip to Him.  I think that’s the first principle. The goal of interpretation is to make real that which is “of God.”   That is:  to give it substance.  I think this is what is meant by “glorifying God.”  It’s visibly living out His image.
Think through whatever portion of the Bible you chose.  Isn’t so very much of it exhortative (ie, trying to get you to do--to make real--something?)  Even the more theoretic parts are actually foundational to the pragmatic parts.  This starts to cleave off Gnostic ideas of spirituality that promote esoteric special knowledge; that knowledge obtained with no hermeneutics applied. That knowledge that can only be  conceptually known by those who are “in the know.”
I’ve been involved in conversations where people have told me that I would understand if I had spiritual understanding.  Or, others, which have started the conversation with, “God told me that you...”  In such conversations I have thought of what I call the Reciprocity Problem.  That’s basically, “What if it were the other way around?”  Maybe I’m the one that has the spiritual understanding and the other person doesn’t.  They’re just confused and a bit too extroverted about it.  My point is:  How would we know?  Is there a special, third hippocampus that gets fired up in these special people?  The authority that is attributed to the Spirit is quite like it is pulled out of the wind (cross-linguistic pun intended...πνεύμα).  It seems to me that we’re both just humble creatures searching for truth.  So, I think:  Maybe it’s the humility (or the hope of humility) that is characteristic of spiritual discernment.
Communication Spans Time And Space And Beyond
Also, let me turn off one interpretation of what I just said, since I’m not saying that.  That was not to say that incarnational interpretation is not eternal or even heavenly.  That is to wrongly suggest I’m saying that it only has to do with the here and now and “of this world.”  I think an important question to ask when people completely discount this world is this:  Where do you love?  Love is here and now.  It also “never fails.” (1 Cor. 13:8).  So, God’s communication to us has to get feet and walk in this world. The spiritual activity of love transcends time and space, but it is also immanent in time and space.  I’ve often thought that “spiritual discernment” is not something the mind or the understanding does.  It’s done by living out in community what spirituality actually is and can be seen when the “fruit of the Spirit” is evident. (Gal 5:16-26).  Like when the “lights go on in your mind’s eye” when you see a group of people express a high degree of unity to accomplish something beautiful.  We might express that as, “That was of God!”  Admittedly, that’s subjective, but, then again, so is discernment.
Belief and Value System Are More Basic
It’s also not to say that “belief” and “value system” are not more basic than “knowledge” (Don’t you just love double negatives?).  See 2 Peter 1.  “Add to your faith, virtue, to virtue, knowledge...”  Virtue is the measurement of positive value.  My point here is that hermeneutics is applied at the “knowledge”  level, but “faith” and “virtue” are logically more basic.  So, there’s a distinction or a delineation of these pieces.
By the way, you can easily see “virtue” as prerequisite to “knowledge” by looking at what science activities get funded and which ones don’t.  It’s the value system, what is held to as virtuous, that picks from the list of choices.  Surprisingly, you actually pick what you are going to know!  In other words, you can’t come to an understanding about certain things if you don’t believe in something (or someone).  And you won’t accept an understanding of something unless you value that which supports it (I use ‘supports’ because that’s a component of the word for ‘add’  (ἐπιχορηγέω) in 2 Peter 1:5).  I think a lot of the talk about “spiritual discernment” is not so much about discernment as it is actually simply reflecting the socio-psychology distinctions expressed in 2 Peter 1:5-7.  Perhaps ‘discernment’ is “faith” plus “virtue”, working together in their support of “knowledge”.  And maybe it's 'faith' and 'virtue' that we label 'Spirit' when we can't quite put our finger on how we know something.  Which is not to say that both can't be correct.
Meaning and Words Are Two separate Things
Interestingly, Paul (2 Cor 12:1-5) references his being talked to in heaven itself.  He relates that he can’t talk about it.  Was that because he was told not to say anything?  Or was it simply there was no way to communicate such ...ummmm...stuff to others?  Note:  the word ἔξεστι (verse 4), translated ‘permitted’ can just as easily be translated ‘possible’.  Is this an example of some kind of communication that cannot have hermeneutics applied to it?  Very likely.  Paul had meaning expressed to him; he did not have words he could express to others.  The danger here is that someone might interpret this as a standard for normal.  This injects Gnosticism into the text since the text as related by Paul is obviously him describing something highly not normal (he’s proving he can boast if he needs to, but that simply underscores that self-serving boasting is a sign of a false Apostle.)   Hermeneutics works with words (and the huge complexity of how communication works) to get to meaning.  But, it’s very easy to conflate the two.  They are separate.
God Has Given Us A Level of Independence To Produce Maturity
I would like to add one more thought.  Communication, by God’s design, requires both sides of the communication to engage.  In Linguistics, these people are call interlocutors.  The idea of “interlocking” is evident in a communication act.  We can actually see this engagement in the form of the word:  commune-i-cation.  Perhaps a main goal in the Spirit’s work is to get us engaged, with Him and with each other.   How else would we mature?  Passive involvement does not mature anyone.  Ask any teacher about the difference between passive and active students.
I think this is one goal, perhaps the main goal, Paul has in mind in 1 Cor. 14.  The engagement between people speaking prophetic truth to each other was to produce the spiritual fruit of love.  I don’t think a person would mature, alone on an island, with a Bible.  In fact, I don’t think he would understand very much of it, other than in a simple 2  +  2 = 4 sort of way.

For extracting salvational truth from the Holy Scripture - yes! By all means! Impossible without Holy Spirit!
Yet a plain common sense and grammatical decency (or decent grammaticality) is sometimes enough to extract a correct meaning, without reference to Holy Spirit. For instance, one can be and remain an atheist, but still realize that Christ cannot be considered as anything less than God due to the words and deeds ascribed to Him; but this atheist can remain an atheist and simply acknowledge the system of Biblical values, without believing that Bible and its system of values is God-ly inspired, but regarding all values as humanly created.
Another question is how the mentioned common sense and grammatical decency are related to Holy Spirit? Can be said of a decent atheist grammarian that in virtue of this very decency he is unawares befriended by Holy Spirit? Is not this a fantastic question, as a matter of fact?
