Does a LLM need to "understand" in order to be a useful tool in Hermeneutics?
There are 2 questions here:
What criteria are there so that something/someone can be considered of having understanding of something?
Does an LLM even need to fulfil these criteria in order to be a tool in the tool set of Hermeneutics?
Context:
https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5136/32251
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/95280/32251

Please refer to my answer on question of the 2nd link. LLM uses popularity as one of its critiria, its ability is "to analyse sources", not "to understand sources".

@VincentWong Yes and how does this answer this question here? Is "understanding" necessary to be useful? This question assumes that LLMs don't understand but questions if this inability is even a problem for hermeneutics.

@VincentWong Even "analysing" is overstating what an LLM can do. It can process sources through it's algorithm, but it doesn't use any reasoning to do so.

@telion - Instead of reading yourselves hundreds of articles, LLM only give you pieces of articles that in its algorithm of training, "useful to you". Is it a problem for hermeneutics? not necessary. Eventually it is the readers determine the final outcome. LLM is just a tool.

@curiousdannii - I believe the developers of LLM are endeavoring to give it a 'free will', employing a social norm approach to discern what is deemed right or wrong. It does possess reasoning capabilities, but its reasoning evolves throughout its training, akin to individual experiences, make it unpredictable.

"Useful for what?" is the question.
LLMs are akin to giant predictive text engines. They're very good at their job, and if you use them for that job they're great. But it doesn't make sense to use them for something else.
So some people have a lot of success using LLMs for proof reading. They're very good at returning typical phrases. But even then, if you give it a truly unique and abnormal text, I'm not sure how well it could proof read it for you, if it has nothing similar to compare it to. Can they handle neologisms for example? I'm not sure if the current generation of LLMs operate at the morpheme level or only the word level, which would determine whether they can correct agreement mismatches or not.
If you have a common question, then LLMs can give you common answers to them. Probably. They are statistical black boxes, so you can never be sure exactly what combination of factors resulted in the answer. And considering that they give many different answers to the same prompts rather than the same text every time, there must be some randomness inherent in the system too. I suspect people are only turning to LLMs for these common questions because search engines like Google have become much harder to extract helpful answers from, as they've been gamed by low quality algorithmically generated websites. While LLMs can't be so directly contaminated by spammers like that, LLMs still are at risk of contamination too, unless their source corpuses are tightly controlled. But that limits their applicability to niche interests.
Beyond that you're into the danger territory. For example, let's say you want to ask an LLM for the parsing of a Greek verb. Maybe the LLM's source corpus included someone parsing that exact verb. If that's the case, then maybe you'd get a useful answer from it. But remember that every part of an LLM's output is statistical. If the correct parsing is "present middle subjunctive" then each of those words is a role of the dice. The more times a text in the source corpus included the correct parsing the more likely it is to give you the correct parsing, but if it's a rare word then the output will be less predictable. And there's no special algorithm inside the LLM that processes Greek verbs, so the black box might just get things completely wrong and feed you the parsing of a completely different verb, or maybe even a noun!
What about if you try to ask an LLM about something that nothing in its source corpus discussed? LLMs are designed to give plausible sounding responses to every input. They're not designed to know when to say "I don't know". They're not knowledge ontology systems, so they don't even have a database they could consult to check whether they have data on a topic. (Things may change as they gain the ability to do their own internet searches.) It's always just a statistical response to the input.
I just tried asking ChatGPT to parse a Greek "word" I made from splicing two other words together. It can't even get the script of the word right.

What is the parsing of προσολύμων?
The word "προσολύμων" (prosolymōn) appears to be a transliteration of a Greek term into the Latin alphabet. However, without context or knowledge of the specific term, it's challenging to provide a precise parsing.

And that's despite it actually occurring in several actual books (I don't know what it really means, maybe it's someone's name?)

"if you give it a truly unique and abnormal text," The Bible hardly falls in that category, does it? I mean in a sense, yes, but it is a well-known text, so no surprise for an LLM.
"They're not designed to know when to say "I don't know".  => "https://chatgpt.com/share/0416d5eb-6925-447b-9f23-63f3c1bf9161
Also did you not provide an example yourself where the LLM tells you it doesn't know (προσολύμων)? Sure I think it happens that the AI is hallucinating information, but that is a problem that will be mitigated over time.

" just a statistical response to the input." you seem quite hung up on this argument, but the whole point of LLM is to weigh the probabilities in the right direction so that the answer is more correct. This can result in a machine that is simply better at a lot of knowledge than humans. In a way, it is a better form of Google and I would assume you use Google for your research as well, correct? I see that LLMs produce different answers as a problem too, but I don't think that problem is big enough to not use or at least explore the usage of LLMs for hermeneutics.

""Useful for what?" is the question." Correct, so let's explore it. You just made a list of very specific use cases where an LLM of today might struggle, but a future one may not. Dismissing them is IMO the wrong way to deal with them because people WILL use LLMs for biblical interpretations. We have the opportunity here to explore the Dos and don'ts, as well as fact-check the LLM. Also, this platform is public so the contents here might be used to train the LLMs.

@telio Write your own answer if you have other use cases.

@curiosdanni done. Sorry took a bit to write.

@telion No need to apologise for taking time to write something! No one had any time expectations here.

Does a LLM need to "understand" in order to be a useful tool in Hermeneutics?
My answer would be No. I don't expect any tool to understand anything, because I judge tools on their usefulness and ease of use.
In Hermeneutics it can get a bit confusing since the general goal is to achieve the "understanding of one Biblical passage"  - @curiosdannii
(https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4079/32251)
To achieve this understanding there are a multitude of ways you can go about from simply reading to extensive historical and linguistic research and methods.
Now how can a LLM come into the picture here? And for whom can they be useful?
Well, there first we need to establish the level of expertise here:

Level one: Novice (Someone who simply reads the bible and is interested in the meaning of a text. Think of a 19-year-old or someone who recently converted that you met at church.
Level two: Experienced (People who did a bible school, studied a bit of theology or just have decades of experience in the field but are not formally educated)
Level three: Expert (People who research hermeneutics, are formally educated, and try to find new knowledge or understanding.)

For Novices LLMs have the greatest benefit but also the greatest risk.
In general, an LLM is very good at introducing someone to a new topic, regardless of the previous expertise, although previous expertise improves the performance of the LLM by a lot. The risk is greater however because of the lack of knowledge comes a lack of ability to verify the information provided by an LLM.
Nevertheless, LLMs are very good at generally explaining something and are also good at staying on point.
E.g.: https://chatgpt.com/share/a80cdb3d-bfb8-4a59-86f0-839acfc73e90
Prompt: In Deuteronomy 25,4 what does the rule practically prevent doing?

(Generated AI Content)
Deuteronomy 25:4 states, "You shall not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain." This rule practically prevents the owner or handler of the ox from preventing the animal from eating some of the grain while it is working.
The context of this rule is agricultural: during the process of
threshing grain, oxen would be used to trample or drag a threshing
sledge over the harvested crops to separate the grain from the chaff.
If the ox was muzzled, it would not be able to eat any of the grain as
it worked, which would be considered cruel and unfair to the animal.
By forbidding the muzzling of the ox, the rule ensures that the
working animal can eat and be sustained while performing its labor.

As a novice and also an experienced this answer is on-point, easy to understand and you get a better picture of the historical context and reason for creating such a rule.
For an expert, this answer is not enough because an expert expects historical proof/citation for such statements. This is something that LLMs admittedly struggle with today.
However, time will tell if LLM will overcome this challenge.
Again, I am not saying there is no risk of such an answer being wrong or inaccurate. This problem is especially difficult in theology and hermeneutics, where you can't simply "test" the answer like you would while programming.
What LLMs are great at as well are definitions: https://chatgpt.com/share/b601d835-b2c4-4be8-ba56-242c77ed3415
Prompt: What is "Messiah"?

(Generated AI Content)
The term "Messiah" has different meanings and connotations across
various religious, cultural, and historical contexts. Here are the
primary interpretations:

Judaism: In Jewish belief, the Messiah (Mashiach in Hebrew) is a future Jewish king from the Davidic line who is expected to be anointed with
holy anointing oil and will rule the Jewish people during the
Messianic Age. This period is anticipated to be a time of global peace
and prosperity, and the Messiah is seen as a human leader, not a
divine figure.

Christianity: In Christianity, the term "Messiah" is synonymous with Jesus Christ. Christians believe that Jesus is the promised Messiah and
Savior prophesied in the Old Testament. The belief is that Jesus, as
the Messiah, fulfilled the Messianic prophecies through his life,
death, and resurrection, bringing salvation to humanity. [...]



As you can see here LLMs are even able to pick up contextual differences of meanings of a word. This works best with languages the LLM has been trained with. Since an old Greek LLM does not exist to my knowledge, it will struggle with that.
Of course, those definitions don't originate from well-established authors, but that is also not what the prompt has asked for.
This is also very important when working with LLMs: LLMs are limited by the prompt/question that is given to them.
So what happens if you ask ChatGPT for a famous quote or definition:
Prompt: Can you quote a well-established Christian author who defined the term Messiah?

(Generated AI Content)
"God has landed on this enemy-occupied world in human form. And now, what was the purpose of it all? What did He come to do? Well, to teach
of course; but as soon as you look into the New Testament or any other
Christian writing, you will find they are constantly talking about
something different - about His death and His coming to life again. It
is obvious that Christians think the chief point of the story lies
here. They think the main thing He came to earth to do was to suffer
and be killed. [...] The central Christian belief is that Christ's
death has somehow put us right with God and given us a fresh start."
— C.S. Lewis, Mere Christianity

Lets compare that to the actual quote: https://allnovel.net/mere-christianity/page-11.html

God has landed on this enemy-occupied world in human form. And now, what was the purpose of it all? What did He come to do? Well,
to teach, of course; but as soon as you look into the New Testament or
any other Christian writing you will find they are constantly talking
about something different�Cabout His death and His coming to life
again. It is obvious that Christians think the chief point of the
story lies there. They think the main thing He came to earth to
do�Cwas to suffer and be killed. [...] The central Christian belief is that Christ's death has somehow put us right with God and given us a fresh start.

A comparison tool like https://text-compare.com/ does only pick up differences in formatting or punctuation. The only arguable difference would be:
"[...] chief point of the story lies there." vs. "[...] chief point of the story lies here."
But I don't see a big semantical difference here. If it was a human I would have assumed a typo.
So LLMs can quote accurately. Doesn't mean they do it every time but they can. This is also the reason why I asked for this benchmark question to explore the accuracy of bible quotes: How trustworthy is ChatGPT 3.5, GPT‑4o and GPT‑4 with bible quotes?
Whether this quote is the most useful can now be debated, but if not satisfied one can simply ask the LLM for a different one and specify what one is looking for.
These are just 2 examples of how LLMs can be used. The big issue here is to find out how LLMs can be used as well as how prompts should be constructed to help achieve the goal of understanding a passage of the Bible.
Another use case could be summarizing large chunks of texts like lengthy commentaries, sermons, or interpretations. However, this is not tightly tied to hermeneutics but can speed up reading and text analyses.
Here I wanted to construct a bad example for a prompt that deliberately makes the LLM produce a wrong/inaccurate/opinionated answer but my first attempt failed:  https://chatgpt.com/c/b5d308ef-24d2-4fcf-995a-b164db38f7d0
Maybe that is a question for another time.
Now for an "expert" question, I picked a random question from BH.SE that has a high score.
What does it mean to be "born of water"?
This the response of chatgpt: https://chatgpt.com/share/9eafacf6-3c36-48a8-8174-c5b3fc855664
However, I think it is a bit difficult for me to make a good assessment of that response, as I can only compare it to the answers on BH.SE in this case.
I summary I hope I demonstrated a few use cases where a LLM can help with certain steps of hermeneutics.
